# External SSD causes mount to hang

Tags: usb, mount, drive

I have an external SSD connected to my computer running Ubuntu 22.04. Previously the drive would just pop up and mount automatically. When that did not happen I tried to mount it manually but the mount command just froze. I have tried the following commands to gather some more information:

sudo dmesg

```
[2750343.429612] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[2750343.450582] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0080, idProduct=a001, bcdDevice= 2.03
[2750343.450592] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2750343.450596] usb 4-2: Product: External USB 3.0
[2750343.450599] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
[2750343.450601] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 2015033100063
[2750343.456566] scsi host0: uas
[2750343.457490] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TO Exter nal USB 3.0      0203 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[2750343.458897] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[2750343.460013] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[2750343.460018] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[2750343.460206] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[2750343.460209] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[2750343.460590] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[2750343.460964] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[2750346.811308] kauditd_printk_skb: 239 callbacks suppressed
[2750346.811317] audit: type=1400 audit(1667919642.844:111220667): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=1825137 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[2750346.811321] audit: type=1400 audit(1667919642.844:111220668): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=1825137 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[2750346.811322] audit: type=1400 audit(1667919642.844:111220669): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.discord.discord" name="/proc/482633/cmdline" pid=1825137 comm="Utils" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[2750346.811324] audit: type=1400 audit(1667919642.844:111220670): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=1825137 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[2750346.811325] audit: type=1400 audit(1667919642.844:111220671): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=1825137 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[2750346.811329] audit: type=1400 audit(1667919642.844:111220672): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=1825137 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[2750346.811336] audit: type=1400 audit(1667919642.844:111220673): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=1825137 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[2750346.811349] audit: type=1400 audit(1667919642.844:111220674): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=1825137 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[2750346.811356] audit: type=1400 audit(1667919642.844:111220675): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=1825137 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[2750346.811369] audit: type=1400 audit(1667919642.844:111220676): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=1825137 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
```

lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 016: ID 0080:a001 Unknown JMS578 based SATA bridge
Bus 004 Device 013: ID 2357:0601 TP-Link UE300 10/100/1000 LAN (ethernet mode) [Realtek RTL8153]
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 06cb:00f0 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 30c9:000f Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsblk

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0   6.3M  1 loop /snap/curl/1113
loop2         7:2    0  63.2M  1 loop /media/nickshiell/disk
loop3         7:3    0 163.3M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1635
loop4         7:4    0 400.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
loop5         7:5    0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop6         7:6    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop7         7:7    0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/582
loop8         7:8    0   238M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1993
loop9         7:9    0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17029
loop10        7:10   0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14
loop11        7:11   0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/599
loop12        7:12   0  72.8M  1 loop /snap/core22/310
loop13        7:13   0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/discord/143
loop14        7:14   0 414.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/29
loop15        7:15   0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1695
loop16        7:16   0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17336
loop17        7:17   0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1634
loop18        7:18   0   6.3M  1 loop /snap/curl/1256
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   500M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   128M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   350M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 110.2G  0 part /media/nickshiell/E2A2C1AAA2C1840F
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  93.3G  0 part /media/nickshiell/New Volume
└─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0 727.1G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
```

The drive is sda (but no numbers appear) and it is connected to USB by "Bus 004 Device 016: ID 0080:a001 Unknown JMS578 based SATA bridge"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT 1:

I tried the following command that I found as a solution to a similar problem:

sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda

with the following result:

```
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
e2fsck: No such device or address while trying to open /dev/sda
Possibly non-existent or swap device?
```

EDIT 2:

After leaving the drive plugged in for sometime, it appears to have connected since an icon appears in the taskbar. However when I try to click it I get the error "Unable to Access  an operation is already pending"

Comment: Does the drive show up in the `mount` and `df` commands?

Comment: No it doesn't for either command.